# Creating custom pop-up without opening another window

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I am trying to create a custom pop-up box for my website that would look something like i currently have for the "contact me" tab when selected.  I would like something that I could easily change the content in.  I would also like for it to automatically load only once per visitor per week.  If you have any suggestions they would that would be great thanks.

- on page load
- i don't need a button for users to click to open pop-up
- shows up once per user per week (cookie)

I can get you more information as needed

Please check out collin-doctor.webs.com and click "contact me" to see a better idea of what I am talking about.

Thanks

Comment: you want this popup page to open when the user login

Comment: You can have the last time popup opened date in database. And once the user login, you can calculate the no. of days from the date field in database with current date then you can open the popup once the user login

Answer (score 0):

i would use a div element, have the divs style's display set to none. Then when ever a user comes to your site you can check the date with javascript, so say every monday we want the popup to show. So what we would do is if the day is monday change the divs display to block. As for checking the visitor part you will need to do something with php. Gets the users ip and save it to a database or a file. Then when the user comes to the site check their ip against the logs if the haven't had the popup yet load the page that has the javascript to load the popup otherwise load the page that doesn't have the javascript. Anyway the code to do the first part to my solution is as follows

```
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        #popup {
            border: 1px solid #000000;
            width:100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 0px auto;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        function showHide(id) {
            var d = new Date();
                if(d.getDay() ==1)
                    document.getElementById(id).style.display ="block";     
        }
    </script>

    </head>
    <body onLoad="javascript: showHide('popup');">
        <div id="popup">Add content here</div>
    </body>
</html>
```